# change a variable value inside a struct using callback from adc peripheral

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I am currently programming PIC microcontroller.

When a struct is created with the way I do, does the address of the variables of that struct change everytime I try to access them?

Or is it like a static variable, meaning the address is decided at compilation time and will not be changed throughout the program? (I think it does not change but I'm not sure.)

```
struct {
   unsigned char age;
} arda_t;
```

Comment: "When a struct if created the way I do [lots of word]" -- please consider showing the actual code. We're pretty good at reading code, there's a risk you're not as good at describing code in other words.

Comment: Now the question title doesn't match the question.

Comment: I'not sure what you're asking here, but if the `arda_t` is a _global_ or a _static_ variable, the address will not change during the execution of the program. If it is a _local_ variable, it's address will of course stay the same during the execution of the scope where it it declared, but the address is subject to change between different executions of the scope, but that doesn't matter because anyway a _local_ variable does not even exist outside the scope where it is declared.

Comment: Depends on if it's a global or automatic variable for one. Why are you asking ?

Answer (score 0):

It is static (at a set memory address) only **if declared in a global scope**. The memory address is decided by the linker and stays put.

You said the struct was declared "using a callback," implying that you're declaring this variable within a function. In that case, its address may be different each time the function is called as the variable only "exists" for the life/scope of that function.

If you want a callback/interrupt to access the variable that already exists, you could make that variable global (available to the entire program) or static global (available just to that file).